# How to make android spinner show same item always instead of changing

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

Long story short. I want my spinner to always show same first item "Add". When item selected from the list it should be gone from the list and the specific action happen. The text "Add" should still appear on spinner. So my question is how to make that spinner always show first item on his dataList? PS. I made that first item in the list don't show when drop down is open.

My layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_add"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorButton" />
```

Method to set spinner adapter with data list:

```
    private fun fillAddSpinner() {
        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_add)
        val titles: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        titles.add(resources.getString(R.string.add_advanced_filter))
        for (filter in tableAdvancedFilters) {
            titles.add(filter.title)
        }
        val dataAdapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String?>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,
            titles as List<String?>
        ) {
            override fun getDropDownView(
                position: Int,
                convertView: View?,
                parent: ViewGroup
            ): View {
                var v: View? = null
                // If this is the initial dummy entry, make it hidden
                if (position == 0) {
                    val tv = TextView(context)
                    tv.height = 0
                    tv.visibility = View.GONE
                    v = tv
                } else { // Pass convertView as null to prevent reuse of special case views
                    v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent)
                }
                // Hide scroll bar because it appears sometimes unnecessarily, this does not prevent scrolling
                parent.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
                return v!!
            }
        }
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = dataAdapter
    }
```

I want it stay the same like it is now:

[image: My spinner]

After user selects one item from spinner I will render specific filter choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to programmatically set spinner selected item use the following: `spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX_OF_ITEM)`